# Error using jaxb external bindings customization

Tags: java, jaxb, weblogic, jax-ws, wsdlc

I use the wsdlc tool (weblogic 10.3.1) to generate classes from wsdl.
I have the following external jaxb bindings customization file:

```
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    schemaLocation="web/WEB-INF/....xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <jaxb:bindings  node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:globalBindings>
            <xjc:superClass name="my.MySuperClass" />
        </jaxb:globalBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

The error message on complilation is: cannot find symbol my.MySuperClass.
And from javac: "package my does not exist". The classpath = everything I include via `<pathelement location=` etc. and 60 lines from eclipse plugins. The problem lies in the javac command that wsdlc initiates. The classpath of this command is correct (hard coded paths e.g.) but still "package ... does not exist".

The usage of wsdlc from ant is like so:

```
<path id="class.path">
  <pathelement path="${java.class.path}" />
  <pathelement location="... hard coded path on disk to a jar" />
</path>

<target name="generate-ws-from-wsdl">
<wsdlc failOnError="true"
       srcWsdl="${basedir}/web/WEB-INF/ps.wsdl"
       destImplDir="${basedir}/src"
       destJwsDir="${basedir}/web/WEB-INF/lib"
       srcPortName="PsPort"
       type="JAXWS">
    <binding file="jaxb-bindings.xml" />
    <classpath refid="class.path" />
</wsdlc>
</target>
```

Comment: Can you echo ${java.class.path}

Comment: Does it contain `my.SuperClass` ?

Comment: It does, I tried putting my.MySuperClass in a jar and adding <pathelement location="src/test.jar" /> but no difference.

Comment: This sounds silly but can you try to declare classspath as attribute of wsdlc instead of sub-element

Comment: I tried <wsdlc ... classpathref="class.path" ...> No difference. The classes are generated, but subsequent compilation and jar fails.

Comment: Maybe this can help, note the test.jar at the end: this jar contains all my self-made java files.

[wsdlc] javac -d D:\workspaces\poc\web\WEB-INF\lib\generated -classpath C:\bea1031\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\bea1031\jrockit_160_05_R27.6.2-20\lib\tools.jar;
D:\workspaces\poc\src\test.jar;

Comment: What is that space between `tools.jar;` and `D:\workspaces\poc\src\test.jar`?

Comment: I suppose a "typo". There is no space in the console output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't jar my classes properly, I thought I could use WinZip to quickly add some classes to a jar, but the 'path' in WinZip was not equal to the package name in java. It took me a while but I learned something about classpaths.

Comment: Use winrar for dirty things like this :) At least, the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

`my.SuperClass` has to exist already, `wsdlc` won't generate it for you.  When it comes to compiling the generated code (which is where I assume is what is failing here), it's because javac can't find `my.SuperClass` in its classpath.

Comment: the class exists under the src tree, i run from ant, perhaps i should change the classpath there?

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the excerpt of the `build.xml` showing how you use use the `wsdlc`.

According to the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webserv_ref/anttasks.html#wp1075710):

> In addition to the WebLogic-specific
>   wsdlc attributes, you can also define
>   the following standard javac
>   attributes; see the Ant documentation
>   for additional information about each
>   attribute:
>
> - `bootclasspath`
> - `bootClasspathRef`
> - `classpath`
> - [...]
>
> You can also use the following
>   standard Ant child elements with the
>   wsdlc Ant task:
>
> - `<FileSet>`
> - `<SourcePath>`
> - `<Classpath>`

Did you specify the classpath to include `my.SuperClass`?

Comment: see my edit, my superclass is in java src tree, all generated files end up in a jar under web/WEB-INF/lib/..._wsdl.jar